# Standard Truffle assertions documentation

Tags: truffle

I have found [Assert.sol](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-core/blob/master/lib/testing/Assert.sol) which is the code that defines the standard Truffle assertions.

Is there a document which describes the available functions? An index would be useful as a start...